# Change spinner dropdown item text color and text size

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-databinding

I'm using android databinding and as part of that, I have a spinner with items (array declared in strings.xml) as

```
android:entries="@string/items"
```

Now I would like to change the text color and size of the dropdown items.
I want to do this with out creating a separate layout for item and using it through java (passing the item layout to array adapter and setting that adapter to the spinner).

I tried many ways and searched everywhere but didn't find appropriate solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner`.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    android:theme="@style/Spinner"
                    android:entries="@array/special_fx_arrays"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"/>
```

Here the style to put in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/red</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Amazing answer, especially since you don't need to implement anything programmatically. One thing to note, though, is that this will only work when using `android:theme`, as using `style` doesn't work for every property, and viceversa. You can always use both at the same time (`theme` and `style`) to ensure all properties are correctly overridden. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a style and set it to spinner through xml

```
 <style name="customStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
 </style>
```

set `customStyle` to your spinner

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new xml with a textview and its properties:
   `my_spinner.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="12sp"
   android:textColor="#f51111"
/>
```

Luego set el nuevo xml en el `ArrayAdapter`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.my_spinner,data);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```